# Detecting EOF in C

Tags: c, stdio

I am using the following C code to take input from user until EOF occurs, but problem is this code is not working, it terminates after taking first input. What's wrong with this code?

```
float input;
 
printf("Input No: ");
scanf("%f", &input);
    
while(!EOF)
{
    printf("Output: %f", input);
    printf("Input No: ");
    scanf("%f", &input);
}
```

Comment: Note: Assuming the user input is not piped, checking for EOF is probably not ideal, since IIRC usually that means the user must hit ctrl+D to quit, which is non-obvious

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`EOF` is just a macro with a value (usually -1). You have to test something against `EOF`, such as the result of a `getchar()` call.

One way to test for the end of a stream is with the `feof` function.

```
if (feof(stdin))
```

Note, that the 'end of stream' state will only be set **after** a failed read.

In your example you should probably check the return value of scanf and if this indicates that no fields were read, then check for end-of-file.

Comment: And note Brian's comment:  stdin doesn't normally register EOF, since there's always more the user can type.  On a Unixy system, that usually means control-D.

Comment: It depends what you mean my 'normally'. If you've redirected stdin (file or pipe, unix or windows), EOF is usually signalled correctly. In an interactive unix terminal ^D usually works, in windows text mode, ^Z at the start of a line works.

Comment: How can you tell where it failed? like If I ask it to read 4 bytes, and it encounters EOF at 2 bytes, how will it tell me that the request was partially fulfilled?

Answer (score 9):

`EOF` is a constant in C. You are not checking the actual file for EOF. You need to do something like this

```
while(!feof(stdin))
```

Here is the documentation to [feof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/feof/). You can also check the return value of [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/). It returns the number of successfully converted items, or `EOF` if it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: does the FILE function contain a variable that would be better to test than using EOF? it just seems like it'd be better to check a status on the actual file pointer, than using some strange function that only works half the time.

Answer (score 4):

Another issue is that you're reading with `scanf("%f", &input);` only.  If the user types something that can't be interpreted as a C floating-point number, like "pi", the `scanf()` call will not assign anything to `input`, and won't progress from there.  This means it would attempt to keep reading "pi", and failing.

Given the change to `while(!feof(stdin))` which other posters are correctly recommending, if you typed "pi" in there would be an endless loop of printing out the former value of `input` and printing the prompt, but the program would never process any new input.

`scanf()` returns the number of assignments to input variables it made.  If it made no assignment, that means it didn't find a floating-point number, and you should read through more input with something like `char string[100];scanf("%99s", string);`.  This will remove the next string from the input stream (up to 99 characters, anyway - the extra `char` is for the null terminator on the string).

You know, this is reminding me of all the reasons I hate `scanf()`, and why I use `fgets()` instead and then maybe parse it using `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

as a starting point you could try replacing

```
while(!EOF)
```

with

```
while(!feof(stdin))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the result of scanf() to make sure there was a successful conversion; if there wasn't, then one of three things is true:

1. scanf() is choking on a character that isn't valid for the %f conversion specifier (i.e., something that isn't a digit, dot, 'e', or 'E');
2. scanf() has detected EOF;
3. scanf() has detected an error on reading stdin.

Example:

```
int moreData = 1;
...
printf("Input no: ");
fflush(stdout);
/**
 * Loop while moreData is true
 */
while (moreData)
{
  errno = 0;
  int itemsRead = scanf("%f", &input);
  if (itemsRead == 1)
  {
    printf("Output: %f\n", input);
    printf("Input no: ");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  else
  {
    if (feof(stdin))
    {
      printf("Hit EOF on stdin; exiting\n");
      moreData = 0;
    }
    else if (ferror(stdin))
    {
      /**
       * I *think* scanf() sets errno; if not, replace
       * the line below with a regular printf() and
       * a generic "read error" message.
       */
      perror("error during read");
      moreData = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Bad character stuck in input stream; clearing to end of line\n");
      while (getchar() != '\n')
        ; /* empty loop */
      printf("Input no: ");
      fflush(stdout);
    }
 }
```

Comment: possible infinite loop when clearing to end of line. I suggest ``while (((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && (ch != '\n')) /* void */;`` ad then checking (again) for EOF and setting ``moredata = 0;``

Comment: Please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scanf("%d %d",a,b)!=EOF)
{

//do .....
}
```